# CKEditor - Image Properties dialog is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am using the default Image plugin with the usual values:

```
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', 

                      {
                        filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/app/myimages.html',
                        filebrowserUploadUrl: '/app/myfiles.html',
                        filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/app/myimages.html'
}
```

The image shows up correctly in the editor after selection via image select dialog box.

But when i right-click on the image and select Image Properties menu.
The dialog that opens **does not contain the image URL or width or height etc.** It essentially has no values.

Answer (score 1):

See my comments.  But for me it was overridding onShow().

```js
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
   // Take the dialog window name and its definition from the event data.
   var dialogName = ev.data.name;
   var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
   
   if ( dialogName == 'image' ) {
    /*dialogDefinition.onShow = function() {
     this.selectPage( 'info' );
    };*/ // do not override this function, it will cause a JS on save (setCustomData can not be found on null object), and the edit image will not fill in its fields.
    
    dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'Link' ); // remove these tabs
    dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'advanced' );
    dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'Upload' );
    
    var contents = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
    //contents.remove( 'htmlPreview' ); // will cause a JS error if disabled.
    contents.remove( 'ratioLock' );
    contents.remove( 'txtHSpace' );
    contents.remove( 'txtVSpace' );
    contents.remove( 'txtAlt' );
    contents.remove( 'txtBorder' );
    
    contents.get('txtWidth').width = 'auto';
    contents.get('txtHeight').width = 'auto';
    contents.get('txtUrl').disabled = 'disabled';
   }
  });
```

Comment: You can override dialog.onShow
See my answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341516/upload-image-cannot-read-property-setcustomdata-of-undefined/45011169#45011169

Comment: The proper way to disable 'txtUrl' field is

contents.get('txtUrl').disable()