# Upload Image: Cannot read property 'setCustomData' of undefined

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to embed into the editor an uploaded image.  My `filebrowserUploadUrl` is `/api/m/image` and it seems to be working fine. After I clicked the `Send it to the Server` button, there is a script error as follows:

```
image.js?t=H4PG:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCustomData' 
of undefined
  at textInput.onChange (image.js?t=H4PG:19)
  at textInput.n (ckeditor.js:10)
  at textInput.CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
  at textInput.setValue (ckeditor.js:619)
  at textInput.setValue (ckeditor.js:545)
  at a.q (ckeditor.js:841)
  at ckeditor.js:31
  at Object.callFunction (ckeditor.js:31)
  at image?CKEditor=editor&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en:1
```

The last line in the above is the call to `filebrowserUploadUrl` and the response from that is:

> window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1, '/images/bulletins.jpg', 'Uploaded successfully');

The `Uploaded successfully` message is shown in an alert. The Preview box under `Image Info` tab is not updated. But if I clicked OK to close the dialog, the image (bulletins.jpg) is embedded in the editor alright.

What could be causing the error and how do I fix it?

---

I found what was causing it. I wanted to set the default tab when the insert image dialog is launched to the Upload tab. I use the following code:

```
CKEDITOR.on("dialogDefinition", function(ev) {
  var dialogName = ev.data.name;
  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
  if (dialogName === "image") {
    dialogDefinition.onShow = function() {
      this.selectPage("Upload");
    }
  }
});
```

When the above code is used, that error happens when a file is uploaded.

Comment: I am facing the same issue after using onShow event handler.

dialogDefinition.onShow = function() {
  console.log('onShow called');
}

can someone help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue, and after using proposed solution from vikram, editor was generating error while pasting image link into the text. Better approach here, not to completely override default `onShow` method, but add more to it in the following way:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if (dialogName == 'image') {

        var oldOnShow = dialogDefinition.onShow;
        var newOnShow = function () {
            this.selectPage('Upload');
            this.hidePage('Link');

            // change tabs order
            $('a[title=Upload].cke_dialog_tab').css('float', 'left');
        };

        dialogDefinition.onShow = function () {
            oldOnShow.call(this, arguments);
            newOnShow.call(this, arguments);
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After debugging a lot I found a solution on this.

If you will see `onChange` method of `txtUrl` textBox in [image.js](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js)
See line number 507 and 513
you will understand cause of this error.

at line 513 `setCustomData` is called.

> original.setCustomData( 'isReady', 'false' );

```
CKEDITOR.on("dialogDefinition", function(ev) {
  var dialogName = ev.data.name;

  //current editor
  var editor = ev.editor;
  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

  if (dialogName === "image") {
    dialogDefinition.dialog.on('show', function(e){
      var dialogBox = e.sender;

        //This line is the answer of your question
       //this line will get rid of the error setCustomData
      dialogBox.originalElement = editor.getSelection().getStartElement();
      this.selectPage("Upload");
    });
  }
});
```